How can I achieve mentioned Json output from Linq EF in C#
I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and trying to get below Json output of my Linq query of two tables:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "product_id": "1",
      "name": "Product 1",
      "image": "/Conten/product_image/1.jpg",
      "attrs": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "weight": "500 Grams",
          "price": "1.300",
          "old_price": "1.300",
          "qty": "5"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "weight": "1KG",
          "price": "1.300",
          "old_price": "1.300",
          "qty": "5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "product_id": "2",
      "name": "Product 2",
      "image": "/Conten/product_image/2.jpg",
      "attrs": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "weight": "250 Grams",
          "price": "0.700",
          "old_price": "0.700",
          "qty": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "weight": "2 KG",
          "price": "1.300",
          "old_price": "1.300",
          "qty": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I have two tables

tblProducts with columns product_id, name, main_image
tblProduct_attr with id, product_id, attr_value, price, old_price, qty

tblProduct_attr contains multiple attributes of 1 product.
This is my Linq code to join those two tables:
var _products = (from p in db.tblProducts
                 join a in db.tblProduct_attr on p.product_id equals a.product_id
                 select new
                 {
                     product_id = p.product_id,
                     name = p.name,
                     image = p.main_image,

                     id = a.id,
                     weight = a.attr_value,
                     price = a.price,
                     old_price = a.old_price,
                     qty = a.qty
                 }).ToList();


Don't use an explicit join, set up a navigation property relationship and let EF manage the join and re-composing the desired projection. The issue with a JOIN is that it results in a Cartesian Product, basically a flattened version of the relationship where if each product has several attributes you get a row per each attribute with the product details appended flattened in single rows, where you want to display the related hierarchy.
Your Product entity should have a collection of Attributes mapped to the Product_Attr table and joined on the ProductId in both tables.
public virtual ICollection<ProductAttribute> Attributes { get; } = [];

From there we can project the desired output:
var products = db.tblProducts
    .AsNoTracking() // recommended for read operations to avoid querying tracking cache.
    .Select(p => new
    {
         product_id = p.product_id,
         name = p.name,
         image = p.main_image,
         attrs = p.Attributes.Select(a => new 
         {
             id = a.id,
             weight = a.attr_value,
             price = a.price,
             old_price = a.old_price,
             qty = a.qty
         }).ToList()
   }).ToList();

Behind the scenes EF will create the Cartesian but re-constitute the relationships into the desired projection.  You can also consider adding an .AsSplitQuery() to remove the Cartesian entirely, executing two queries to build the products and attributes.

You can remove AsNoTracking, EF do not track custom projected objects, especially anonymous.

Actually it can make a difference. While projections do not put anything into the tracking cache, EF will still inspect the tracking cache for tracked entities to fill references, the check does appear to occur even when there are no references to populate. I stumbled upon this when I was writing an article on projection and performance tuning and where I went to demonstrate AsNoTracking not being needed only to find the performance notably slower than when I added it.  It's only a factor if the context happens to have a number of entities tracked, so not usually a concern.

I'm sorry that I didn't mentioned that project created in MVC 5 with C# 7.3, but your code requires C# 12 for ICollection.
And please can you explain more how can I do it in C# 7.

Use List<ProductAttribute> instead of ICollection.

Still same error,
CS8370 Feature 'collection expressions' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 12.0 or greater.

Ah.. the public virtual ICollection<ProductAttribute> Attributes { get; } = [];.. Just use public virtual ICollection<ProductAttribute> Attributes { get; } = new List<ProductAttribute>();  the  = []; is a newer shorthand for initialization. If that still complains you might need { get; private set; }. Feels like a LONG time since I used VS2017 :)

I have achieved Json as required using Steve Py's answer.
var products = db.tblProducts
.AsNoTracking()// recommended for read operations to avoid querying tracking cache.
.Select(p => new
{
    product_id = p.product_id,
    name = p.name,
    image = p.main_image,
    attrs = p.Attributes.Select(a => new
    {
        id = a.id,
        weight = a.attr_value,
        qty = a.qty,
        price = a.price,
        old_price = a.old_price,
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();

I have added:
public virtual ICollection<tblProduct_attr> Attributes { get; set; }

in tblProduct model file, and code works perfectly without explicit join.
Thank you very much Steve Py, and sorry I have bother you a lot.

This is a thank you comment, please write it as a comment to the accepted answer.
